# updateQuery returns 1 but it's not getting reflected in db (spring data jpa)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

But updation works with below code snippet

```
 Department department= departmentRepository.findOne(300L);
 department.setName("rajiv");
 departmentRepository.saveAndFlush(department);
```

but then this scenario being onetone mapping it could be a case where i would end up hitting 3 queries which include 2 select queries and one one update query .
To optimize the way i update it i'm trying to use this approach which is not getting updated thought executeUpdate() returns affected row as 1 .

Comment: and with below scenario it's not working          /* @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
     @Query("update Department d set d.name =:name where d.id=:id")
     int update(@Param("name")String name,@Param("id")Long id);*/
    
        /*departmentRepository.update("Jerry",300L);*/

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your query.

You have used the **=** operator instead you should have used the **like** operator

---

You can also take help of **@NamedNativeQueries**

Example

**DepartmentRepository.java**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
public List<Department> update(Long id);
```

**Department.java**

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="updateResult", columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "count")})

@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Department.update", 
        query = "UPDATE departmemnt SET name like 'rajiv' WHERE id = ?",
        resultSetMapping = "updateResult")
})
```

NativeQueries works more faster than normal Hibernate Queries

Answer (score 0):

Yeah may this would help , in case of spring data i found a way to make it updatable and since they insist to use @transactional and extend the functionality of jparepository and now it hits only one line of statement

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
@Query("update Department d set d.name =:name where d.id=:id")
int update(@Param("name")String name,@Param("id")Long id);
```

in case if i choose to for nativeQuery

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
@Query(value="update Department d set d.name =:name where d.id=:id",nativeQuery=true)
int update(@Param("name")String name,@Param("id")Long id);
```